# Powershell script does not run via Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

PowerShell script runs fine manually, but doesn't run in  Task scheduler.
The script:

```
$env:CLIENTNAME | Out-File C:\Users\tst5clj\Desktop\folder\log.txt -Append
```

I tried another command($env:COMPUTERNAME) and works fine both manually and via PowerShell.

Comment: Question is a little confusing... Is the entire script you are trying to run just printing the environment variable 'CLIENTNAME' to a file? How are you scheduling this in Task Scheduler? Is there any error or output? Is the environment variable 'CLIENTNAME' actually set on the system? It is set on the User?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a .ps1 script from a scheduled task, your task's action should be configured as follows (at a minimum)

- Action: Start a program
- Program/script: powershell.exe
- Add arguments (optional): -executionpolicy bypass -file  "{Absolute}\{Path}\{To}\script.ps1"

And your script.ps1 can run whatever code you need.

```bsh
# Setup for example
$env:CLIENTNAME = 'Contoso'

$env:CLIENTNAME | Out-File "$PSScriptRoot\log.txt"
```

Here's a similar Q&A: [How to execute PowerShell script on Task Scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609527/how-to-execute-powershell-script-on-task-scheduler?noredirect=1&lq=1)