# How to create and schedule a task in windows task scheduler using powershell commands?

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I want to create and run task in windows task scheduler using powershell commands.

I have a script and want to schedule task for this script only by using powershell commands not by gui interface.

Please provide a solution as soon as possible......

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell script does not run via Scheduled Tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259951/powershell-script-does-not-run-via-scheduled-tasks). There so many examples of Scheduled Task manipulation on SO. Maybe that one will help

Comment: @Matt I think he wants to schedule tasks using powershell, not the other way around (run powershell scripts using the task scheduler).

Answer (score 1):

[I would use `schtasks.exe`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx)  No need to reinvent the wheel.  You can either import from an XML file or create it from the command line.

Just because you're using Powershell doesn't mean everything you're doing must be with a cmdlet or .NET objects.  Indeed, many things you'll want to do aren't even exposed in .NET.  You'll need to use Win32 or COM objects to get them done.

Comment: Is there a Win32 or COM object interface for the Windows Task scheduler?

Comment: @tgun926 [Of course there is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).