# How to interrogate multiple text files for certain key words and output results in text?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Here is my objective:

1. I have a networked folder (Windows 7) that contains text log files that are generated on daily basis (1 log text per day), as a result file names contain various dates.
2. I need a script to go in and scan each new log file for a list of certain keywords: "ABC", "DEF", "GHI". Then write out how many of these events were found in each log file and save this info in a text format or similar.

Issues I'm facing: how do i get around various file names, each file name contains that days date. How do i look through a list of keywords and count all of these words in each log file. How do i write out the results in a separate text file. And finally is there a way to automate all of this?

I would like to stay in PowerShell or use Windows batch files.

Comment: Yes, this can be done. `Select-String` I think would play a BIG part of this. For automation you could consider a scheduled task. Please limit your post to one question. [scheduled tasks are covered on SO for PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259951/powershell-script-does-not-run-via-scheduled-tasks) so you should be able to find help for that

Comment: thanks. scheduling this is the next step. i tried select string, still trrying to figure out how to search for mutliple parameters and report them in a readable table with all events counted and located across multiple log files

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid your request is not clear and have several missing details. However, here it is a Batch file with what *I guess* could be the first attempt to get a solution:

**EDIT**: I modified the original code in order to also group the files per event; the first code just groups events per file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Push dir to the networked folder
pushd "\\Path\to\networked\folder"

rem Count all file/event combinations in a two-dimensional array
for %%a in (ABC DEF GHI) do (
   for /F "delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /I /L "%%a" logFiles*.txt') do (
      set /A "count[%%~Nb][%%a]+=1"
   )
)

rem Group events for the same file
for /F "tokens=2,3* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do (
   set "file[%%a]=!file[%%a]!, %%b (%%c)"
)

rem Show the final result 1: events per file
(
   echo Events per file:
   for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set file[') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      echo %%a.txt = !line:~2!
   )
) > result1.txt

rem Group and count files for the same event
for /F "tokens=2,3* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do (
   set "event[%%b]=!event[%%b]!, %%a.txt (%%c)"
   set /A "eventCount[%%b]+=%%c"
)

rem Show the final result 2: files per event
(
   echo Files per event:
   for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set event[') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      echo "%%a" - !eventCount[%%a]! found in !line:~2!
   )
) > result2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. How does it get around variable dated file names?

Comment: Perhaps if you explain what "variable dated file names" means I may modify the code accordingly. You should post a list with several file names and the desired result. Please, modify the original question, do NOT post additional information in comments! BTW, I read _in a comment to other answer_ **`:/`** that perhaps you want the "transposed" results (files per event), so I modified my code for this result; see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell we can use Get-Childitem to collect which files we want to search though and store those in a variable as such:

```
$Content = Get-Content (Get-Childitem -Path C:\Temp\*.txt)
```

Once those text files are stored into our Content variable we can simply use the -match regex operator to find a match inside that collection of files.

```
$Content -match "Bacon"
```

You could then out this information using Out-File:

```
$Content -match "Bacon" | Out-file C:\Temp\Bacon.txt
```

Of course with the Get-child item you can use the DateTime operator and narrow down your query for only recently changed text files as required.

If you want to get more technical we can use Select-String to get this output for multiple matches as such:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Logs |
  where { $_ | Select-String -Pattern 'Blahblah' } |
  where { $_ | Select-String -Pattern '\d{4}' } |
...
```

You can also do it on one line:

```
gci C:\Logs| select-string -pattern '(Bacon.*Failed)|(Failed.*Steak)'
```

Outputting is up to your imagination really. Once they are just simple strings they can be put into an array or a custom PS object for nice output. it would just require you to save the command you were running into a variable then call it later for the export.

for Grouping, take a look at Group-Object cmdlet. it will give you the occurrence numbers.

Comment: 1. Can i pass multiple -match parameters? "ABC", "DEF" etc.? 2. in the out file is there a way to generate a table with results such as: parameter "ABC" - 10 (found 10 times) - "1-1-15_log.txt" (log file where it was found); "DEF" - 3 (found 3 times) - "1-2-15_log.txt" (log file where it was found) etc