# unable to access Security event log from powershell script through schedule task

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fetch Windows Security event logs from Powershell script through schedule task for every one hour, i am running schedule task with Highest Privileges but still i am getting "Unauthorized operation" it works fine from Powershell ISE with admin, I added permissions at HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\eventlog\Security and gave read/ write access but still same issue, kindly help me.

Below is the script. 
script updated

```
#Security log
$ScriptStart = Get-Date
$PreviousTime = $ScriptStart.AddHours(-1)
$destination= '\\servername\Security_Logs\'
$output = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Name).Name
$dest = "$destination$output$Date"
if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dest)) {
New-Item -Type Directory -Path $dest | Out-Null
$security = Get-WinEvent  @{ logname="security"; starttime=$PreviousTime;endtime=$ScriptStart } | select logname,timecreated,id,LevelDisplayName,message 
if ($security) {
 $security | Export-Csv $dest\Security.$Date.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
} else {
'no files to copy' | Set-Content "$dest\nofile.txt"
}
}
```

Comment: Make sure you launch task scheduler as admin when creating the task.

Comment: No luck , still same issue

Answer (score 0):

How do you launch it in your job scheduler? Perhaps it would make sense to have that information included.

Maybe the upvoted answer here
[Powershell script does not run via Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259951/powershell-script-does-not-run-via-scheduled-tasks)
Can help you launch it properly.

```
powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\path\event4740.ps1
```

Comment: I call powershell script from bat file , 
batch file contains  : powershell.exe -file c:\log-file-path\script.ps1
schedule task settings : 
program/script : c:\logfile-path\\bat.bat
start in (optionl): c:\logfile-path\
I am not able to run the powershell script directly from schedule task so I created a batch file and scheduled batch file in schedule task

Comment: Could you try with:

    
      powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file c:\log-file-path\script.ps1

Comment: script is running but unable to get security events

Comment: Did you set the task to run as SYSTEM (Not just Administrator, but SYSTEM on the localhost)

Comment: when i run task with SYSTEM it is running for long time and not getting security events.

Comment: Sounds like there's a bug in your script.
Is the script postet in the Original Post, the entire script?

Comment: updated full script can you check and let me know if any bugs

Comment: Does it create the folders you tell it to, on the remote server ? ($Destination, $dest)